# time difference in Windows batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

When you load D:\script2\IIS\timeln.txt , the time is written in one line like 09:15:05

I want to calculate this time by subtracting it from the current time

ex) 10:48:20 - 10:15:05 = 00:33:15
or 1995 seconds

I want 01:33:15 or 1995 seconds to be saved as a text file and remain

Answer (score 1):

You can use the New-TimeSpan function within PowerShell.

```
(New-TimeSpan -Start 10:15:05 -End 10:48:20).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: I want to load D:\script2\IIS\timeln.txt and subtract it from the current time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get time string from file
$timeFromFile = Get-Content 'D:\script2\IIS\timeln.txt'

# Get timespan by substracting time form file from current date/time 
$diff = [datetime]::Now - [datetime]$timeFromFile

# Get the total seconds and round 
[System.Math]::Round($diff.TotalSeconds)
```

Edit

```
# Check if seconds > 900
if ($diff.TotalSeconds -gt 900){
    # do something
    Write-Host "Time difference is greater than 900 seconds"
    $diff.TotalSeconds | Out-File 'D:\script2\IIS\result.txt'
}
```

Comment: I want to save that result as a txt file, but it doesn't work. What should I do

Comment: You want to save the total seconds to a file?  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Is it impossible to print the message that appears when it is over 900 seconds?